# Amchart bullet round not working in Stock Chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have added the `bullet: "round"` property to Stock graph but it doesn't show up for all stock graphs.

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/jay-raj/pen/PORPVo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using multiple dataSets, you also have to set the equivalent `compareGraph*`-named properties to achieve the same visuals as the main/first dataSet that's using the regular graph properties. In your case, you have to set [`compareGraphBullet`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph#compareGraphBullet) to `"round"` in the second panel's stockGraph:

```
stockGraphs: [{
    id: "g2",
    valueField: "value2",
    compareField: "value2",
    comparable: true,
    bullet: "round",
    compareGraphBullet: "round",
}]
```

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/120273dcaf1f82ff7e25e842cb3b6531/)